# mod_rails. Apache + Nginx. After installing passenger Apache doesn't start

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, phusion-passenger, gentoo

I've installed Nginx for optimizing the speed of Apache requests. For some weeks everything was fine, all my sites had started to fly indeed. BUT, I've decided to install passenger, and has broken my Apache. It's not starting... So, I think it's because the port 80 already in use by Nginx
netstat shows such situation:
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3932/nginx.conf`
The error when trying to start Apache is saying:
`(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs`                          
So, how can I fix my apache to work it again? BTW I've recompiled it to be as prefork :-D
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot, Alex

Answer (score 2):

You have to use another port. Try to search in /etc/apache2 directory in some configuration file directive 'Listen' and change it in this way, for example:

```
Listen 81
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I've looked to vhosts directory and saw that after recompiling apache for prefork it has created the file 00_default_vhost.conf with 80 port. So I've just marked it as .bak and everything is working well now. Thanks!